# Result of Differ.compare() vanishes after using once

Tags: python, difflib

I am trying to describe the differences between two strings by using the result of `compare(a,b)` method of `Differ` class defined in `difflib` in python. I am using `compare(a,b)` in the following manner.

```
s1 = ["one",  "three", "twoo"]
s2 = ["one",  "tow", "tree"]
d = difflib.Differ()
result = d.compare(s1, s2)

# without this for loop, the result is as expected
for r in result:
    print(r)

desc = describe_diff(result)
for k, value in desc.items():
    print(k, value)
```

My problem is when I print the `result` before passing it to the function `describe_diff` which I created, the result is wrong. But when I comment out the for loop that prints `result`, the output is ok. I have tried printing the `result` using two for loops one right after the other, but it gets printed only once. However, when I insert the `compare(s1,s2)` in between the two loops, (or between the printing loop and my `describe_diff` function call) everything is fine. So to use the value of `result` more than once do I have to execute the `compare` method every time? There must be some way to get around this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `compare` gives you a generator object, which will be exhausted after iterating over it once. You could cast the generator to a list if you want to use the result multiple times.

The generator will be empty after one iteration:

```
>>> from difflib import Differ
>>> s1 = ["one",  "three", "twoo"]
>>> s2 = ["one",  "tow", "tree"]
>>> result = Differ().compare(s1, s2)
>>> result
<generator object compare at 0x7f017de9f1b0>
>>> for x in result:
...     pass
... 
>>> list(result)
[]
```

Casting the generator to a list (before iterating over it):

```
>>> result = Differ().compare(s1, s2)
>>> list(result)
['  one', '+ tow', '- three', '?  -\n', '+ tree', '- twoo']
```

Note that after you cast the generator to list, it will be exhausted again:

```
>>> result = Differ().compare(s1, s2)
>>> foo = list(result) # foo is now ['  one', '+ tow', '- three', '?  -\n', '+ tree', '- twoo']
>>> list(result)
[]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know what generators are and how they work. It seems like I should have taken a look at the return type of `compare` method from documentation before posting a question here.

Comment: In fact the example in documentation shows that they did make a list first. This is from the documentation: `>>> result = list(d.compare(text1, text2))`